# Create an object in Visual Basic (not VB.NET) without using "New"

Tags: vb.net, oop, object

I've been told to think outside the box, and think of a way to create an object in VB without using the new keyword. I was told it is possible but i'm having trouble figuring it out. I know primitive data gets stored on the stack and the reference to the objects get stored there too but the actual memory space for the object is in the heap and that new does that for us. When i try it without new i mostly get null reference exception, any ideas on how this is possible?

```
Dim objTest as TestOne()

'some class named TestOne with empty Constructor
```

Comment: What happens if you evaluate an expression like `(1+2).ToString()`?

Comment: its for older visual basic.

Comment: Maybe you should specify what that older version is and edit your question accordingly.  We shouldn't have to guess stuff like that.  You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  What language it's for is obviously part of that.

Comment: I've changed the title to specify this is a VB question, not VB.NET - as per OP's comment.

Comment: OP, can you confirm whether this is VB or VBA?

Comment: visual basic only

Comment: i dont understand how is there confusion when i specifically said visual basic with no mention of .NET or VBA

Comment: @a-exelle, nowadays the term VB refers to VB.NET rather than the original Visual Basic. Because the latter is very old and no longer used much.

Answer (score 2):

In VB you can use the [CreateObject function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/createobject-function) if you have an existing class defined in a COM library that you've created - or a COM library that already exists.

As an example, create a project reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime COM library (scrrun.dll). To do this in the VB IDE select **Project**, **References**, then pick the reference '*Microsoft Scripting Runtime*'. You can then write the following code:

```
Dim fso As Object
fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Comment: do i need to import something because it does not work. also set keyword is no longer supported by VB. .

Comment: @a-exelle, I've now made my answer VB-specific.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done VB for quite a while now, but the *Activator* exists in both C# and VB. Here's couple lines of C# that you can convert to VB:

```cs
var newThing = (TestOne)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestOne));
newThing.ID = 5;
```

The *CreateInstance* method returns an object, which I convert to the correct class with

```cs
(TestOne)
```

which is the C# syntax for type conversion. Sorry, I forgot how to do this in VB.

Where class 'TestOne' looks like:

```cs
class TestOne {
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Note that 'Activator' is part of .NET [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: when i try this it says testone is a class type and cannot be used as an expression

Comment: i was able to get it to work, thank you very much i just had to use getType instead of type of. you were helpful so thank you again!

Comment: That's VB.Net, not Vb6. I changed your question tags to VB.Net.

Comment: @MarkJ, the OP's original code indicates the older version of VB (so not VB.NET). And in a comment on October 27, the OP says it's the older version of VB. So now I'm really confused!

Comment: I share your confusion to be honest! But VB.Net first came out in 2002 so it certainly could be described as "older" 17 years later... And the OP said that `Set` is no longer supported in VB in one comment - that's true, it is no longer supported *in VB.Net*.The original code in the question could be VB6 or VB.net. `Activator.CreateInstance` in this answer is certainly VB.Net and the OP says it works for them. That's why I went with VB.Net.